# Google+ API call to update user avatar?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

Is there a current API call to allow an (Android) app to update a users Google+ avatar?  For Facebook you can upload a photo and then redirect a user to a page to "accept" this as their profile picture; a two-step approach like this might be OK if a single API call is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to do this. You can search for an [existing feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) and file a new one if none exist.